# SideMenu remains open when forms are switched

Tags: codenameone

I have got a problem with the SideMenu (not on top-style): Form A has got a SideMenu. In the SideMenu there is a Button to show Form B. Form B has got a Button to show Form C. And Form C has got a Button to show Form A again. If I go through this chain (call A, then B, then C and then back to A), the SideMenu on Form A is still open when form A is activated from the Button in Form C. Even if I call closeSideMenuBar() when Form B is started it remains open.

Do you have any idea how to fix this? I doubt that the transition of the SideMenuBar will not finish it's job when another form is shown directly. Maybe there is a way to prevent this transition?

Answer (score 0):

There was a regression with the old side menu bar that should already be fixed if you do an update client libs which you can do by:

- Right click the project
- Select Codename One Settings
- Select Basic
- Press "Update Client Libs"